# Use of reference to elements in @_ to avoid duplicating code

Tags: perl

Is it safe to take reference of elements of `@_` in a subroutine in order to avoid duplicating code? I also wonder if the following is good practice or can be simplified. I have a subroutine `mod_str` that takes an option saying if a string argument should be modified in-place or not:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'abc';

my $mstr = mod_str( $str, in_place => 0 );
say $mstr;
mod_str( $str, in_place => 1 );
say $str;

sub mod_str {
    my %opt;
    %opt = @_[1..$#_];

    if ( $opt{in_place} ) {
        $_[0] =~ s/a/A/g;
        # .. do more stuff with $_[0]
        return;
    }
    else {
        my $str = $_[0];
        $str =~ s/a/A/g;
        # .. do more stuff with $str
        return $str;
    }
}
```

In order to avoid repeating/duplicating code in the `if` and `else` blocks above, I tried to improve `mod_str`:

```
sub mod_str {
    my %opt;
    %opt = @_[1..$#_];

    my $ref;
    my $str;
    if ( $opt{in_place} ) {
        $ref = \$_[0];
    }
    else {
        $str = $_[0];  # make copy
        $ref = \$str;
    }
    $$ref =~ s/a/A/g;
    # .. do more stuff with $$ref
    $opt{in_place} ? return : return $$ref;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "in place" flag changes the function's interface to the point where it should be a new function.  It will simplify the interface, testing, documentation and the internals to have two functions.  Rather than having to parse arguments and have a big if/else block, the user has already made that choice for you.

Another way to look at it is the `in_place` option will always be set to a constant.  Because it fundamentally changes how the function behaves, there's no sensible case where you'd write `in_place => $flag`.

Once you do that, the reuse becomes more obvious.  Write one function to do the operation in place.  Write another which calls that on a copy.

```
sub mod_str_in_place {
    # ...Do work on $_[0]...

    return;
}

sub mod_str {
    my $str = $_[0];  # string is copied

    mod_str_in_place($str);

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: @Schwern Excellent design decision

Comment: The proposed `in_place` option is exactly equivalent to the `/r` "non-destructive" modifier of `s///`

Answer (score 5):

In the absence of the disgraced `given` I like using `for` as a topicalizer. This effectively aliases `$_` to either `$_[0]` or the local copy depending on the value of the `in_place` hash element. It's directly comparable to your `$ref` but with aliases, and a lot cleaner

I see no reason to return a useless `undef` / `()` in the case that the string is modified in place; the subroutine may as well return the new value of the string. (I suspect the *old* value might be more useful, after the fashion of `$x++`, but that makes for uglier code!)

I'm not sure whether this is readable code to anyone but me, so comments are welcome!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ss = 'abcabc';
printf "%s %s\n", mod_str($ss), $ss;

$ss = 'abcabc';
printf "%s %s\n", mod_str($ss, in_place => 1), $ss;

sub mod_str {

    my ($copy, %opt) = @_;

    for ( $opt{in_place} ? $_[0] : $copy ) {
        s/a/A/g;
        # .. do more stuff with $_
        return $_;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
AbcAbc abcabc
AbcAbc AbcAbc
```

Comment: This is nice. It's cohesive, it's practical, and it doesn't require polluting the code and symbol table with unnecessary functions.

Comment: @Borodin This is how I was going to recommend solving Hakon's literal question as well.  However, I approve of Schwern's rephrasing it as an XY Problem.

Comment: @stevieb The symbol table isn't a nature preserve. Simplifying a function by splitting it in two is a proper use. Pollution is a module exporting 40 functions with common names when you really need 3.

Comment: +1  I'd like this solution even more if the API were changed to drop `in_place => 1` in favor of `! defined(wantarray)`.